# Wordpress - do_settings_fields undefined function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, function

I have a plugin in WordPress and I am trying to load a panel of options through jQuery and using the ".load ()" function.

For this, I outsourced my panel to a separate ".php" file and on the first line I called "wp-load.php" to use the WordPress functions.

The problem is that it is not recognizing the functions "settings_fields" and "do_settings_fields" but apparently it does recognize the translation functions, for example "__" and "_e".

I do not know what it can be and I do not know if there could be another way to load external content with jquery.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function do_settings_fields() in C:\xampp\htdocs\webs\test\wp-content\plugins\homeandcity\assets\php\new_settings.php on line 19
```

In this way I include the WordPress library:

```
<?php 
    require_once( explode( "wp-content" , __FILE__ )[0] . "wp-load.php" );
?>
```

This is the part of my code in jQuery that loads the mentioned content:

```
    if (data.status == true){
        $('#settings').load(''+pluginUrl+'./assets/php/settings.php');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that the file which contains that function isn't queued to default WP loading process. Try to include it manually.

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-load.php');
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-admin/includes/template.php');
```